# Ensuring a cashier's check is legitimate

Tags: fraud, cashier-check

I'm looking to sell a vehicle for the first time.  I've purchased a few vehicles using cashier's checks, but I've never had to receive one.  Assuming I am willing to accept the risk of a cashier's check (which I'm still debating), what safeguards should I undergo to be confident that it is legitimate.

My intent is to carry out the transaction in my bank, where I have access to a notary, so safeguards which can be done by a teller at my bank are easy for me to do.

Comment: Note: this question came up for me when I was looking into the topic of these checks.  Other answers on StackExchange suggest everything from "cashier's checks are safe" to "cashier's checks are as unreliable as personal checks," so I'm not 100% sure where I stand.

Comment: On all checks you should be able to call the number on the back and verify if there is sufficient funds to cover the amount on the check.  Used to do this when cashing personal checks at a grocery store if over a certain amount to make sure the check would now bounce.

Answer (score 4):

What did the people that sold you cars for cashier's checks do to make sure you were not a scammer? Probably copying the same steps is a good start.

You are on the right track. At your bank they can contact the issuing bank, and validate the cashier's check. Any fake check will not pass that hurdle. While at that you can contact your bank beforehand and ask if you can complete the car sale at the bank office. Usually it is possible, and the bank sees it as an opportunity to reinforce the relationship with the client.

If the seller is a scammer, he would be wary of going to the bank.

Once the check is validated by your bank, its deposit won't be reversed. [See this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/71801/27572).